# When are these other fields in hostent used?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm combing through a simple client socket program to understand how it all works.

When I call `gethostbyname()`, it will fill the various fields in my `hostent` structure. However, the only fields that are used are `h_addr` and `h_length`, when I copy `h_addr` to my `sockaddr_in` structure. When are the other fields used, such as `h_name` or `h_aliases`?

I have a secondary question which I'll just throw in here too.

When we set our `sin_family` field that's in `sockaddr_in` to `AF_INET` (or whatever value we're using), why don't we just copy that from our `hostent` structure's `h_addrtype`, since it's already there?

(BTW, I've read online that gethostbyname() is obsolete, so don't be too concerned with the use of that in my example.)

Comment: Make sure you are looking at the `h_addrtype` field when interpreting the `h_addr(_list)` field. The data can be assigned to a `sockaddr_in` *only* when `h_addrtype` is `AF_INET`. If it were `AF_INET6` instead, the data would have to be assigned to a `sockaddr_in6` instead.

Answer (score 0):

An online [manual page for `gethostbyname`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html) explains that:

- The `h_name` field is used as the "official name of host".
- The `h_aliases` field is used as the "alias list".

But to put this into my own words...

I'd use the `h_name` field to get the proper name for the host since the name by which one calls `gethostbyname` could instead be one of the listed aliases. Alternatively, I'd use the `h_aliases` field if perhaps I wanted to know what other names could be used to refer to the same `hostent` structure.

For example, a company may have a policy that all networked computers must have an official name that's the name of a U.S. state. That could work okay until naming a computer that's going to be the company's web server. `Alabama` may be a fine state and a fine computer but no one's going to expect to have to go the company's web server by using a URL that's like `https://Alabama.thegreatcompany.com/`. Instead it's more common for the URL to be like `https://www.thegreatcompany.com/` (where `www` is before `thegreatcompany.com` not `Alabama`). A way to deal with this is to use an alias for the host named `Alabama` of `www`. This way `Alabama` comes up in the `h_name` field and `www` in the `h_aliases` field.

Regarding the secondary question, you could use the info from the `hostent` structure but then your client would be connecting using the info obtained rather than connecting using info acquired by other means. Nothing necessarily wrong with either. Say for example that your `hostent` information came from an unreliable source. In this case it might be preferred to hard code that information into your client socket program.